# Why call them cycles and boundaries?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have a small question. Why we have this designation: $n$-cycles for $Z_n$ and $n$-boundaries for $B_n$ ? Why they are called cycles and boundaries ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology#Singular_chain_complex

Please.

Thank you.

Comment: The first homology theory was simplicial homology, which is arguably also the easiest homology theory. It's hard for me to describe but the cycles correspond to paths that cycle around and the boundaries are boundaries of certain regions.

Answer (score 0):

I think these designations came from German:

cycle = Zyklus

boundary = Begrenzung

Comment: but why cycles and boundaries ?\

Comment: "Cycles" since the earliest example was loops on surfaces. "Boundaries" since a simple loop of a surface is nulhomologous iff it bounds a subsurface.